# Simplify boolean expression to minimum number of literals

Tags: boolean-algebra

Problem is to simplify this boolean expression:

$(a+b+c')(a'b'+c)$

I expanded it out and simplified to get to $a'b'c' + c(a+b)$ but that doesn't reduce the number of literals. Tried everything I could think of but I must be missing something...

Comment: It doesn't look like it can be simplified further. All it seems to say is that $a + b \iff c$, which can't really be simplified.

Comment: I was wondering that, but I figured that would be too troll for a problem suggesting in its wording that it can be minimized (and which also eventually asks you to draw the logic diagram).

Comment: That is true, I agree with you.But for the moment, I cannot see how to simplify this expression further. I even used Wolfram Alpha in a last ditch, and it could not do it as well. That should be the nail in the coffin.

Comment: Sounds pretty convincing. I suppose we'll wait and see if somebody can come along and out-do Wolfram Alpha :)

Comment: Yes, we shall wait. Until then, +1.

Comment: Wolfram alpha gave the same [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(a+or+b+or+not+c)+and+(not+a+and+not+b+or+c)) as Karnaugh Map optimal. No need to simplify it further under any other measure.

Answer (score 2):

How is this?

[image]

Found using [Logic Friday 1](https://sontrak.com/).